# Using Infopath to build list form, but I want to only use the "time" field from the "Date & Time" preset field?

Tags: list-view, form, date-time, list-form

I am in the process of building a list form using InfoPath for a team's intake form.

There are two separate columns:

- Validation Date
- Time Required

Validation Date will be a date stamp (Jan 1, 2018), meanwhile Time Required will just be the time stamp (12:00am).

The problem is, in my list view the "Time Required" shows both a date stamp and time stamp, even though I only want it to display the time stamp:

[image]

The date stamp highlighted in yellow is what I want either hidden/removed.

The "Validation Date" column used to display the time stamp as well, but I managed to fix it by clicking on some settings that said something along the lines of "show date only". There was, however, no equivalent for "show time only" that ended up working.

Can someone assist? For these fields, I am using the "Date and Time" input from the controls selection in InfoPath:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Unfortunately,** there is no A Time control in InfoPath or Time column in SharePoint list.

---

**InfoPath Workarounds**

Based on the `Validation Date`, try to calculate the `Time Required` as the following:

- Let `Validation Date` show back Date and Time.
- Add a new TextBox as `Time Required` > Set it as Read-only in the control properties.
- Add a new TextBox as `Date Required` > Set it as Read-only in the control properties.
- Now Create a rule, when `Validation Date` **changed** set the `Time Required` with the below formula

  ```
  substring-after(Time Required, "T")
  ```
- Again, create a rule when `Validation Date` **changed** set the `Date Required` with the below formula

  ```
  substring-before(Time Required, "T")
  ```

**Output**

[image]

---

**SharePoint workaround**

Creating a `Calculated Column` to show only time part from `Time Required` Field, then hide the `Time Required` from the list view

```
=TEXT([Time Required],"hh:mm:ss")
```

To Show Date

```
TEXT([Date Required],"mm-dd-yyyy")
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Do your solutions overwrite existing form data? The problem is I'm making modifications to an already deployed list that has thousands of entries, many of these forms were created with data values inserted into "Time Required" already. I'm afraid if I use your solutions, they will either reject, overwrite or completely be an entirely different data column.